# Что такое "кондрашка"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Вчера задавал вопрос о слове "окочуриться" и сразу возник в памяти еще один синоним неясной этимологии - "кондрашка" или, еще лучше, "Кондратий обнял". Откуда пошло это выражение и что за Кондратий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько версий происхождения фразеологизма "Кондрашка хватил (хватила, стукнул, стукнула)" или, как вы говорите, "Кондратий обнял". Ключевым словом здесь является, конечно, Кондрашка (Кондратий).

1. По предположению историка С. М. Соловьева, фразеологизм восходит к имени Кондратия Булавина, бахмутского атамана, предводителя народного восстания на Дону в 1707 г. Одним из эпизодов восстания было внезапное нападение восставших на царский отряд во главе с воеводой князем Долгоруким и разгром его. Но даже сам Соловьев склонен был сомневаться (небеспричинно, есть языковые несоответствия) в полной истинности своего предположения. Да и фразеологизм существовал еще до XVIII в., т. е. до Булавинского восстания.
2. *Кондрашка* в выражении - эвфемистическое наименование смерти, тяжелой болезни, паралича, характерное для народного суеверия. Точно так же смерть эвфемистически называют Курносой, Костлявой, а медведя - Михаилом Ивановичем Топтыгиным и т. п. Возможно, слово *кондрашка* связано с диал. (новг.) *кондрат, кондратий* "друг, товарищ, собрат". Ср. эвфемистические диалектные наименования болезней типа *тетка, мачеха* (Фасмер).
3. Слово *кондрашка* - результат контаминации диал. *кондрат* "друг, собрат" с нем. Kamrat, Kamerad (Фасмер). Но такая трактовка отвергается семантически, т. к. "от собрата до паралича далеко" (Преображенский).
4. Компонент *кондрашка* можно связать с глаголом *драть*, выделяя в нем древний префикс ко- и интерфикс -н-. Это подтверждается тем, что синонимом фразеологизма **кондрашка хватил** является сущ. *удар* (ср. удар хватил), восходящее к тому же корню, что и *драть*.
   Оборот восходит к намеренной антропизации процесса, т. к. существовало табу на прямое наименование смерти. Но сам антропоним *Кондрашка* врутренней формой связан с представлениями об искривлении или затвердении тела при параличе, т. к. слова с корнем -конд-/-кондр- объединены общей идеей затвердения, искривления (по данным Историко-этимологического словаря "Русская фразеология").

Comment: А Вы сами к какой версии склоняетесь?

Comment: Мне нравится версия, связанная с ударом. Все остальные можно вывести из нее.

Comment: Мне тоже она наиболее логичной кажется